# Using erb tags in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra, erb

I'm using Sinatra and Datamapper. In one part of my app, I want to dynamically add new `<select>` elements to a table which acts as a form. The `<select>` element contains all of the elements from my `Personnel` class. If I were to do this in regular ERB, I'd do:

```
<select>
<% @personnel.each do |p| %>
  <option> <%= p.name %> </option>
<% end %>
</select>
```

However, in JQuery this doesn't work. I was wondering if there was anything I could do to dynamically add `<select>` elements like the one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution was incredibly simple. Instead of putting my Jquery script into the `public` directory, as you normally would, the script should be written as part of the .erb template. Then Sinatra takes care of generating proper HTML tags for insertion. You can then use the `<% %>` elements inside of `<script> </script>` - works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also keep the JS file separate from the html by writing a route like this:

```
get '/myscript.js' do
  content_type :js
  erb :myscript
end
```

Of course this can be generalized but i'll leave that up to you ;-)